# How to know the popularity of deno modules

Tags: deno

Since node js maintains all its packages through npm, we get to see the popularity of the packages by weekly and overall downloads.

In deno, since all the packages are module based and available through url on deno site. How to know about the popularity of such third party modules?

Answer (score 5):

### Update:

There's now a label next to the package indicating it's popularity.

[image]

### Old answer

**Short answer:** You can't.

---

Right now there's no way to know those stats you mention since there isn't a centralized package manager.

**deno.land/x** is a URL rewriting service for Deno scripts, nothing else.

Currently, the best way to know how popular a package is, is to check the *star* count on Github, since the majority of the packages are hosted there. Although the *star* count is far from an objective stat since a package can be downloaded a million times and yet have 1 star.